# Not able to see the response message using cURL

Tags: java, curl

I am trying to call an API using cURL.

Using the Advanced Rest Client(ARC) when I send a request using this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/jcr/root/myfolder/integrationTestNode
```

I receive this response:

```
Status:
500: Internal Server Error
Loading time: 37 ms
Date: Thu, 28 Jul 2016 06:20:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 88
```

And a **message**

```
Failed to delete filejavax.jcr.PathNotFoundException: /root/myfolder/integrationTestNode
```

Which is exactly what I want.

But when I try the same using cURL in a shell script I am unable to see the **message**.

Here is the script:

```
url="http://localhost:8080/jcr/root/myfolder/integrationTestNode"
echo ${url}
curl -u amit:pass --verbose -I -X DELETE \
--url "${url}"
echo " ----------------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

And here is the response of the script:

```
http://localhost:8080/jcr/root/myfolder/integrationTestNode
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
*   Trying ::1...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*                                                                                                                 Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'amit'
> DELETE /jcr/root/myfolder/integrationTestNode HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> Authorization: Basic YW1pdDpwYXNz
> User-Agent: curl/7.49.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Date: Thu, 28 Jul 2016 06:25:26 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 88
<
* Excess found in a non pipelined read: excess = 88 url = /jcr/root/myfolder/int                                                                                                                egrationTestNode (zero-length body)
  0    88    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0HT                                                                                                                TP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Thu, 28 Jul 2016 06:25:26 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 88
```

How can I see the **response message** using cURL ?

I am using `javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status().entity("").build()` to send the message.

Comment: You can send any java object in entity() method as a part of your response message. So may be you can put your code in try catch block and if you get any exception then add exception message in Response object. You can find below catch block for example:                                                                  String output = "Failed To Post Data! "+e.getMessage();
return Response.status(500).entity(output).build(); output can be any object you want like map , list ,string etc. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Bhagyashri I have already done that, but it still doesn't work. I have mentioned that as the last line of my question posted above.